# Dúvida sobre métodos e classes estáticas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho uma duvida sobre métodos e classes estáticas, dado o código abaixo:

```
    static List<MaterialRCM> mr = new List<MaterialRCM>();

    [Authorize]
    public void AddMaterial(int Qtd, int Id)
    {
        mr.Add(new MaterialRCM(Id, Qtd));
    }
```

Agora, como classes e métodos estáticos não são tipos por referencia, se dois usuários utilizarem a mesma funcionalidade corre o risco de na lista ter dados dos dois usuários?
Pra ficar mais claro, esse método é chamado via Ajax, cada vez que o usuário adiciona um material esse método é chamado e adiciona o Id do Material e a quantidade na lista, e se dois usuários estiverem solicitando materiais?

Comment: Bom, como você identifica nesse método qual o usuário?

Comment: Bom... não tem nenhuma identificação, mas eu poderia colocar o ID do usuário também, aí não teria problema por que eu teria o ID do usuário que solicitou o material certo? Mas então, a lista conteria os objetos dos dois usuários?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Acho que a questão é: classes e métodos estáticos são globais para toda a aplicação, ou só existem por requisição no MVC?

Comment: @bfavaretto São globais para a aplicação toda. O ideal para acesso concorrente é colocar um `.lock()` em cima do objeto a ser acessado.

Comment: Sim os usuários compartilharam da mesma informação, e cuidado isso é má prática!

Comment: @user3670112 é fácil você perceber tal comportamento, tenha dois navegadores instalados em seu computador, abre o primeiro adicione itens nessa lista. Depois abra o outro, vai perceber que isso vai refletir para o outro navegador, então tome cuidado com esse método não eficaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, não apenas se dois usuários mas qualquer requisição feita ao servidor vai acessar exatamente o mesmo valor.

No geral não é recomendado usar variáveis estáticas com o ASP.Net, não apenas por ter um único valor para todas as requisições mas também pelo fato de poder causar problemas de concorrência, já que o valor poderia ser acessado e modificado por mais de uma thread ao mesmo tempo, se você precisa manter valores no servidor eu diria para usar alguma outra forma, como Session por exemplo.

Comment: +1 Perfeito....